# Create a new record from http post in a python script

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, http-post

I want to create a record in my `poc` model via http post request,
the model has `filed a` and `filed b`

```
@new_test = TestingCounter.create(params["poc"])
```

I finished the request in a Python script, however it can not create a new record in my ROR active record, because I supposed I sent a nested hash data, but it didn't.

How could I fix it?

```
aa={"a":1,"b":2}
body={
"poc":aa
}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response, content = h.request(SERVER_URL, 'POST', headers=headers, body=(body))
```

Rails server console

```
{
           "poc" => "{'a': 1, 'b': 2}",
        "action" => "add_test_counter",
    "controller" => "handy_network_tools"
}
```